# How to move to a tab to edit in Vim

Tags: vim

I have 10 tabs are open in my Vim. I know how to go to next tab by `gt` and previous tab by hitting `gT`.

But I'd like to know how to go to tab 4, 5 or 7 from tab 10?

Comment: What are you doing that requires 10 tabs?

Comment: @romainl i regularly have > 8 tabs open

Comment: @user1281385, I rarely have more than one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just prefix your `gt` command with a number, e.g.:

```
4gt
```

For convenience I have <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> through <kbd>0</kbd> mapped to jump to corresponding tabs (put this in your vimrc):

```
" Meta+1-0 jumps to tab 1-10, Shift+Meta+1-0 jumps to tab 11-20:
let s:windowmapnr = 0
let s:wins='1234567890!@#$%^&*()'
while (s:windowmapnr < strlen(s:wins))
    exe 'noremap <silent> <M-' . s:wins[s:windowmapnr] . '> ' . (s:windowmapnr + 1) . 'gt'
    exe 'inoremap <silent> <M-' . s:wins[s:windowmapnr] . '> <C-O>' . (s:windowmapnr + 1) . 'gt'
    exe 'cnoremap <silent> <M-' . s:wins[s:windowmapnr] . '> <C-C>' . (s:windowmapnr + 1) . 'gt'
    exe 'vnoremap <silent> <M-' . s:wins[s:windowmapnr] . '> <C-C>' . (s:windowmapnr + 1) . 'gt'
    let s:windowmapnr += 1
endwhile
unlet s:windowmapnr s:wins
```

Comment: This use case is exactly why I show the tab number in the tabline: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Show_tab_number_in_your_tab_line